# get function name inside it

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, hunit

I have a bunch of functions like: `method1`, `method2`, `method3`. For all of them there are `HUnit` test functions like: `testMethod1`, `testMethod2`, `testMethod3`.

```
testMethod1 = TestCase $
  assertEqual "testmethod1" ...

testMethod2 = TestCase $
  assertEqual "testmethod2" ...

testMethod3 = TestCase $
  assertEqual "testmethod3" ...
```

I would like to avoid redundant copying of function's name as prefix of error
message and call it something like that:

```
testMethod1 = TestCase $
  assertEqual_ ...
```

How can it be achieved (any "magic" trick is appreciated)?

So actually question is how can function name be taken inside of it's definition?

---

**Update**.

It's not actually clear from original question, that I wanna handle that type of situation too:

```
tProcess = TestCase $ do
  assertEqual "tProcess" testResult $ someTest
  assertEqual "tProcess" anotherTestResult $ anotherTest
  assertEqual "tProcess" resultAgain $ testAgain
```

Finally I want to write something like that:

```
tProcess = TestCase $ do
  assertEqual_ testResult $ someTest
  assertEqual_ anotherTestResult $ anotherTest
  assertEqual_ resultAgain $ testAgain
```

Comment: My old question could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896928/how-to-get-variable-name-in-haskell

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do this directly (i.e. so that your test case starts with `testMethodN = ...`), but you can use [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell) to get this:

```
testCase "testMethod1" [| do
    assertEqual_ a b
    assertEqual_ c d
 |]
```

This involves writing `testCase :: String -> Q Exp -> Q [Dec]`, a function to turn the name of the test case and a quoted expression into a list of declarations. For instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
    
import Data.Char
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Data.Generics

assertEqual :: (Eq a) => String -> a -> a -> IO ()
assertEqual s a b = when (a /= b) . putStrLn $ "Test " ++ s ++ " failed!"

assertEqual_ :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> IO ()
assertEqual_ = error "assertEqual_ used outside of testCase"

testCase :: String -> Q Exp -> Q [Dec]
testCase name expr = do
    let lowerName = map toLower name
    e' <- [| assertEqual lowerName |]
    pure <$> valD
        (varP (mkName name))
        (normalB (everywhere (mkT (replaceAssertEqual_ e')) <$> expr))
        []
  where
    replaceAssertEqual_ e' (VarE n) | n == 'assertEqual_ = e'
    replaceAssertEqual_ _ e = e
```

The basic idea here is to generate a definition of the name given, and replace every occurrence of the variable `assertEqual_` in the quoted expression with `assertEqual lowerName`. Thanks to Template Haskell's [Scrap Your Boilerplate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb) support, we don't need to traverse the entire AST, just specify a transformation for each `Exp` node.

Note that `assertEqual_` must be a bound identifier with the correct type, since the quoted expression is typechecked before being passed on to `testCase`. Additionally, `testCase` must be defined in a separate module than the one it's used in, due to GHC's stage restriction.

Comment: This means that reflection is not supported?

Comment: @Riccardo: Allowing you to simply access the name of a function from inside it would be rather impure. Even in Lisp, a language known for its metaprogramming, the solution is to use a macro facility (in this case, Template Haskell).

Comment: I've updated my answer to support multiple assertions per test case :)

Comment: By the way, `assertEqual` is from `Test.HUnit` module ⇒ there is no need in rewriting it. And `testCase` using actually looks like  `testCase "method" [| TestCase $ do ... |]`

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers explain how to do this with metaprogramming, but one way to *avoid* the issue is to have anonymous tests which take their name as an argument.

We can then use a `Data.Map` to associate them with their names (in this case I'm just using raw Assertions, plus some syntactic sugar from the `map-syntax` package):

```
import Data.Map
import Data.Map.Syntax
import Test.HUnit

assertEqual_ x y n = assertEqual n x y

Right tests = runMap $ do
  "test1" ## assertEqual_ 1 2
  "test2" ## assertEqual_ 1 1
  "test3" ## assertEqual_ 3 2
```

To run these, we can fold the `Data.Map` using a function which:

- Takes the name and assertion-waiting-for-a-name as arguments
- Passes the name to the assertion-waiting-for-a-name
- Passes the resulting `Assertion` to `TestCase`
- Runs the `TestCase`
- Binds to another monadic action, using `>>`

We use `return ()` as our default monadic action:

```
runTests = foldWithKey go (return ()) tests
    where go name test = (runTestTT (TestCase (test name)) >>)
```

This gives results like:

```
> go
### Failure:
test1
expected: 1
 but got: 2
Cases: 1  Tried: 1  Errors: 0  Failures: 1
Cases: 1  Tried: 1  Errors: 0  Failures: 0
### Failure:
test3
expected: 3
 but got: 2
Cases: 1  Tried: 1  Errors: 0  Failures: 1
```